# How to get a view from within Espresso to pass into an IdlingResource?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-espresso

I essentially have a custom `IdlingResource` that takes a `View` a constructor argument. I can't find anywhere that really talks about how to implement it.

I'm trying to use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32763454/1193321

As you can see, it takes a `ViewPager`, but when I'm registering the `IdlingResource` in my test class, I'm not sure how I can get my view.

I've tried `findViewById()` and I've tried getting the currently running activity and then calling `findViewById()` on that, with no luck.

Anyone know what to do in this scenario?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Figured it out. To get the view to pass into an idling resource, all you have to do is take the member variable of your ActivityTestRule

**For example:**

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MainActivity.class);
```

and then just call `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewId)`

So the end result is:

```
activityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewId);
```

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer works as long as a test is running in the same activity. However, if the test navigates to another activity `activityTestRule.getActivity()` will return the wrong activity (the first one). To address this, one can create a helper method returning an actual activity:

```
public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    final Activity[] currentActivity = new Activity[1];
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Collection<Activity> allActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance()
                    .getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
            if (!allActivities.isEmpty()) {
                currentActivity[0] = allActivities.iterator().next();
            }
        }
    });
    return currentActivity[0];
}
```

And then it could be used as the following:

```
Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
if (currentActivity != null) {
    currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.viewId);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `ActivityScenarioRule` from `androidx.test.ext.junit.rules` (since `ActivityTestRule` "will be deprecated and eventually removed from library in the future"), you can get your `Activity` instance and call `findViewById` method:

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.activityScenarioRule
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) {

    @get: Rule
    var testRule = activityScenarioRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun mainTestCase() {
        testRule.scenario.onActivity { activity ->
            val view = activity.findViewById<YourView>(R.id.view)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't already used `IdilingResources` in `Espresso`, but did you saw these articles:

- [Espresso: Custom Idling Resource by Chiuki](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/espresso-custom-idling-resource.html)
- [Wait for it...a deep dive into Espresso's Idling Resources](http://stefanodacchille.github.io/blog/2014/04/05/wait-for-it/)

Also please check official Android Docs: [Idling Resources (reference)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html)

To answer your question,

- the best way to do it is passing in an instance of one of the Views into the class's constructor. Check: [Calling findViewById() from outside an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393586/calling-findviewbyid-from-outside-an-activity)
- another way is getting view by context. Check [android - How to get view from context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114966/android-how-to-get-view-from-context)

Here's an exmple taken from a link above:

> Starting with a context, the root view of the
>   associated activity can be had by
>
> ```
> View rootView = ((Activity)_context).Window.DecorView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
> ```
>
> In Raw Android it'd look something like:
>
> ```
> View rootView = ((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
> ```
>
> Then simply call the findViewById on this
>
> ```
> View v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
> ```

This might be also useful: [How to call getResources() from a class which has no context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238588/how-to-call-getresources-from-a-class-which-has-no-context)

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for the links and code snippets. I've read through those links before I posted the question. Chiukis blog posts are awesome. But your answer seems awfully "hacky" to me. There has to be a way to get a view object directly from an espresso test no?