# How to get the object for Recycler View which is created dynamically in espresso android?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to find out the coordinates of the view. So,to perform `view.getX()` I need to have the view object.

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683956/how-to-get-a-view-from-within-espresso-to-pass-into-an-idlingresource?rq=1

Comment: @Upendra, I have recyclerView so I am facing difficulty because one Id corresponds to many views here.